# How to write dictionary of dictionaries to .mat file?

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary, io

Scipy's [savemat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html) function allows for saving a dictionary to a .mat file. When the dictionary contains as values dictionaries itself, the respective struct fields remain empty in MATLAB.

Is there another method to save a dict inluding dictionaries to .mat files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error in my case, the keys had numeric names, e.g. "0" or "01".
This is allowed in the python setting, but not in the scipy.io.savemat function, it won't give an error, but no data is written out